# Disable multiple select on same level in material tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use `material tree` to handle data in UI.

I need to have options to select nodes with checkboxes by level.

But I need to restrict users to select only one item on the same level. (only one selected, like radio buttons)

I try t check if already exists item in the `sellectedItem = []` array with the same level, but I hope there is something better or native?

Thnx

Here is a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqiuib-1suwpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts)

```js
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatTreeFlatDataSource,
  MatTreeFlattener,
} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Node for to-do item
 */
export class TodoItemNode {
  children: TodoItemNode[];
  display: string;
}

/** Flat to-do item node with expandable and level information */
export class TodoItemFlatNode {
  item: string;
  level: number;
  display: string;
  expandable: boolean;
}

/**
 * The Json object for to-do list data.
 */
const TREE_DATA: TodoItemNode[] = [
  {
    display: 'Level 1',
    children: [
      {
        display: 'Level 2',
        children: [
          {
            display: 'Level 3',
            children: [
              {
                display: 'Level 4',
                children: [
                  {
                    display: 'Level 5',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            display: 'Level 3',
            children: [
              {
                display: 'Level 4',
                children: [
                  {
                    display: 'Level 5',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    display: 'Level 1',
    children: [
      {
        display: 'Level 2',
        children: [
          {
            display: 'Level 3',
            children: [
              {
                display: 'Level 4',
                children: [
                  {
                    display: 'Level 5',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    display: 'Level 5',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
];

/**
 * Checklist database, it can build a tree structured Json object.
 * Each node in Json object represents a to-do item or a category.
 * If a node is a category, it has children items and new items can be added under the category.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ChecklistDatabase {
  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

  get data(): TodoItemNode[] {
    return this.dataChange.value;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.
    const data = this.buildFileTree(TREE_DATA, 0);

    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }

  /**
   * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
   * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
   */
  buildFileTree(obj: TodoItemNode[], level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return obj;
  }

  /** Add an item to to-do list */
  /*   insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (parent.children) {
      parent.children.push({ item: name } as TodoItemNode);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
  } */

  /* updateItem(node: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    node.item = name;
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  } */
}

/**
 * @title Tree with checkboxes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-checklist-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-checklist-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-checklist-example.css'],
  providers: [ChecklistDatabase],
})
export class TreeChecklistExample {
  /** Map from flat node to nested node. This helps us finding the nested node to be modified */
  flatNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemFlatNode, TodoItemNode>();

  /** Map from nested node to flattened node. This helps us to keep the same object for selection */
  nestedNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>();

  /** A selected parent node to be inserted */
  selectedParent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = null;

  /** The new item's name */
  newItemName = '';

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>;

  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  /** The selection for checklist */
  checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<TodoItemFlatNode>(
    true /* multiple */
  );

  constructor(private _database: ChecklistDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
      this.transformer,
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable,
      this.getChildren
    );
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable
    );
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(
      this.treeControl,
      this.treeFlattener
    );

    _database.dataChange.subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }

  getLevel = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  getChildren = (node: TodoItemNode): TodoItemNode[] => node.children;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.expandable;

  hasNoContent = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) =>
    _nodeData.item === '';

  /**
   * Transformer to convert nested node to flat node. Record the nodes in maps for later use.
   */
  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode =
      existingNode && existingNode.item === node.display
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.display;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children?.length;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  };

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected. */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every((child) => {
        return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
      });
    return descAllSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some((child) =>
      this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child)
    );
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the to-do item selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  todoItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node)
      ? this.checklistSelection.select(...descendants)
      : this.checklistSelection.deselect(...descendants);

    // Force update for the parent
    descendants.forEach((child) => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /** Toggle a leaf to-do item selection. Check all the parents to see if they changed */
  todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /* Checks all the parents when a leaf node is selected/unselected */
  checkAllParentsSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    let parent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = this.getParentNode(node);
    while (parent) {
      this.checkRootNodeSelection(parent);
      parent = this.getParentNode(parent);
    }
  }

  /** Check root node checked state and change it accordingly */
  checkRootNodeSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    const nodeSelected = this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every((child) => {
        return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
      });
    if (nodeSelected && !descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.deselect(node);
    } else if (!nodeSelected && descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(node);
    }
  }

  /* Get the parent node of a node */
  getParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): TodoItemFlatNode | null {
    const currentLevel = this.getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this.getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is anything native our out of the box, for such a particular case

The apprach that I propose involves keeping a list of `TodoItemNode` which are selected by depth/level and also at the same time add a bit more information about each node

1. Add a Depth property to each tree node

```js
export class TodoItemNode {
  id: string /*unique ID in all the tree*/
  depth: number
  children: TodoItemNode[];
  display: string;
}
```

2. Keep a list of currenty selected nodes by depth

```js
    SelectedNodesByDepth :TodoItemNode [] = []
```

3. Any time a checbkox is click at any depth you will:

- check if `SelectedNodesByDepth` contains a `TodoItemNode` at the same depth, if that is the case, unselect the checbox of that node and remove it from the `SelectedNodesByDepth` list
- then select the current one and add it to your list (regardless if the above condition returned true or false)

The Id I have added to `TodoItemNode` will allow you to search more easily in the tree and in the list of `SelectedNodesByDepth`

And In that way you can achieve a similar behavior than a radio button by each depth/level

Comment: Thnx, I will try this.